# How to show or hide a tooltip under specific conditions? IWin32window win?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a tooltip that's working how expected, the only problem is that sometimes i have to change a option, and i don't want him to show anymore.

I tried 2 things:

If the conditions wouldn't apply it would reset as

```
toolTip21.Hide(<programname>);
```

But it would reply a but saying that the programname doesnt exist in the context
It was calling for a IWin32window, but since i'm a beginner i don't quite identify all the kinds of data. Even in msdn the information is very scarce

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.iwin32window(v=vs.110).aspx

interface?? why not window?, or Form1, for example?

I also tried to hide it while in popup, but this was the result

[image]

Any hint? I smell noob stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your screenshot is that you cannot cast ToolTip to Control as it doesn't derive from it (The ToolTip component is not a control).
However, you could cast the sender to ToolTip directly to use the Hide method, that is:

```
((ToolTip)sender).Hide(someControlWithTooltipBeingShown);
```

Still, this is probably not the solution you're looking for.
If this is the only tooltip associated to you ToolTip component, you could play with its "Active" property and set it to true or false depending on if you want to show tooltips or not.
You could do that when the RadioButton changes.
If this is not your only tooltip, you could create a separate ToolTip component to handle just this tooltip and use the same method above.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect solution, changing active to true or false totally did it in the clean way i was looking for. I also tried the code you have on your answer but it would give me an error regardless. What does c# means by a IWIN32window win? What kind of "thing" is this? Is it the form name?

Comment: Sorry, yes. My code takes care of the cast but the "Hide" method actually requires you to pass the control associated with the tooltip you want to hide. I will correct this in my answer. Don't worry too much about the IWin32Window interface, it is a way in which the "handle" the OS uses to refer to a window can be retrieved, just know that every System.Control implements this interface. see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx